Bezier curve in edit mode is very thin
I created bezier curve in Blender 4.2 and when switching to edit mode curve is very thin and barely visible.
I can see and select it and modify but it's quite unusable since you really can't see it specially when editing parts of the curve.
I couldn't find any information how to change "thickness" in edit mode for beziers.

I don't know why there is no way to change the display thickness of a curve, but it is correct that you did not find any information, because there is no way. You can only change the thickness of mesh edges in the Preferences, but not the curve segments. The only workaround would be to give the curve a Bevel > Depth under Geometry to give it a mesh thickness, this will also be visible in Edit Mode.

it doesn't look like you can change its thickness but you could change the world color in the Viewport Shading panel > Background, click on Viewport and change the color

There is a setting in the Preferences to make thicker lines however, but it has just three options: Thin, Default and Thick. This is under Interface > Display. The problem with this is, you cannot individually choose a specific thickness in pixels and it is not changing only the curve segments - it is changing all lines in the interface. For the colors which @moonboots mentions: you can also go to the Preferences and change Themes > 3D Viewport > Wire Edit color to something brighter so that you can see the segments better in Edit Mode.

Final touch: you could reduce your monitor resolution (yeah, this sucks)

@GordonBrinkmann thanks for Bevel trick. Works for me well enough.

Mostly likely, the curves are extra thin  because of your screen resolution (1080p or higher)
This problem is easy to fix by scaling the Blender's UI :
Edit > Preferences > Interface > Resolution Value*
*try values bigger than 1 - like 1.3, 1.5 ,1.8, etc.
This should help to fix your problem.

Well, that setting is right above the line thickness option I mention in the comments - but while the line thickness already has the undesired side effect that all lines of the interface get thicker, the solution in your answer is even worse because it scales the whole interface up, not only the lines... which is not really what the question is about: increasing the thickness of Bézier curves in Edit Mode.

@GordonBrinkmann — >>"the solution in your answer is even worse">> — Is my solution worse or better depends on the reason WHY user's curves are thin. So let's just let the user to decide which setting does better work for him/her
